# What is the font in Grid Diary app?

Tags: font-identification

Grid Diary is a popular diary app on App Store. I love its font but don't what it is. Any ideas?

WhatTheFont cannot give a precise answer because the text is too small.

[image: Grid Diary app screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Museo Sans 300 and Museo Sans 500.

I extracted the files from Grid Diary bundle and I saw these font files.